# Use StringWriter, StringBuilder and XmlTextWriter to load an XML and write it into a string

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlwriter

I have an XML file on a given location and I want to have the content of the XML in a string variable. However, when I print it out, the encoding changes. This is how I am doing it.

```
    XmlDocument xmlFile = new XmlDocument();
    xmlFile.Load(xmlFileLocation);

    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter(new StringBuilder()))
    {
         using (XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
         {
             xmlFile.Save(xmlTextWriter);
         }

         return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
```

When I try to initialize the XmlTextWriter (new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter, Encoding.UTF8)) with a given encoding, then I have issues with the StringWriter but I don't know how to sort it out. Any idea?

The issue is: Cannot convert from StringWriter into Stream

Comment: What's wrong with ``xmlFile.OuterXml`` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407302/convert-xmldocument-to-string)?

Comment: Just use [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx)? It's not entirely clear what you mean by 'the encoding changes', but I'm going to guess it's a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564718/using-stringwriter-for-xml-serialization).

Answer (score 0):

Encoding using `StringWriter` always will be UTF-16 and cannot be changed. When you want to use a `StringWriter` with different encoding it is possible to subclass `StringWriter`. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14743609/9446220) answer on how to do so.

Using your code this would then change to

```
using (EncodingStringWriter eStringWriter = new EncodingStringWriter (new StringBuilder(), Encoding.UTF8))
{
     using (XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented })
     {
         xmlFile.Save(xmlTextWriter);
     }

     return eStringWriter.ToString();
}
```